# SPI TFT LCD on Arduino Uno - blank white screen

Tags: embedded, arduino-uno, spi, firmware, lcd

I am using a 2.4 inch SPI TFT LCD with Arduino Uno, using Arduino IDE.

After uploading the code it is showing only white screen.

Power supply connections:

- VCC - 5V
- Gnd - gnd
- Led - 3.3v

I have installed all the libraries, checked the connections multiple times, tried several provided code examples, but same problem; white screen.

Code is as below:-

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ILI9341.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define TFT_CLK 13    // SPI clock pin (CLK)
#define TFT_MISO 12   // SPI MISO pin
#define TFT_MOSI 11   // SPI MOSI pin
#define TFT_CS A5    // TFT chip select pin (CS/SS)
#define TFT_RST A4     // TFT reset pin (RST/RESET)
#define TFT_DC A3      // TFT data/command pin (DC)
//#define TFT_LED A0

Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST, TFT_CLK, TFT_RST, TFT_MISO);

void setup() 
{
    tft.begin();
    tft.setRotation(0); // Set rotation if required
    tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK); // Clear the screen with black color
    // Set text color to white
    tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
    tft.setTextSize(2); // Set text size
    // Print a text on the screen
    tft.setCursor(10, 10);
    tft.println("Hello, World!");
}

void loop() 
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: You may need to tell us what the display is - perhaps with a link to the product page or datasheet?  I assume from the code that it is based on an ILI9341 driver - but that is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the part has an ILI9341 graphics driver (unstated, but assumed from the code presented), and you have connected it as indicated in the code then, given that the MOSI, MISO and CK pins specified are the Uno hardware SPI pins then you are using the wrong `Adafruit_ILI9341` constructor overload.  You need only specify the DC, CS and RST pins:

```
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341( TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST ) ;
```

You used the soft-SPI constructor and even then failed to specify the MOSI pin (passing instead the RST pin - twice!).

```cpp
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_ILI9341.h"

#define TFT_CS A5      // TFT chip select pin (CS/SS)
#define TFT_RST A4     // TFT reset pin (RST/RESET)
#define TFT_DC A3      // TFT data/command pin (DC)

Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST ) ;

void setup() 
{
    tft.begin();

    tft.setRotation(0); 
    tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK); 
    tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
    tft.setTextSize(2);

    // Print a text on the screen
    tft.setCursor(10, 10);
    tft.println("Hello, World!");
}

void loop() 
{
    
}
```

If you truely intended to use Soft-SPI, then :

```cpp
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_CLK, TFT_RST, TFT_MISO);
                                                        ^^^^^^^^ Correction here.
```